# No Update button on the App Store?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted an application on the App Store yesterday (I have it since few years). I received an email 16 hours ago to say "ready to sale", and now it's available on the App Store in version **10.012** (the right version). Everything is fine.

However, we (two separate iPhones) have the **10.011** version (downloaded from the App Store, so the same certificate), and we saw the "Open" button, no "Update".

We delete the app from one device, redownloaded it, and it was the right **10.012**. I can't say to my users to delete and download the app again...

Why the button is not available ? How Apple detects the update and show the button ? 
By the way, we have uploaded another app with the same process, and it's the same problem.

Comment: In my experience this is normal behavior - I've *never* seen an "Update" button when looking at *any* App Store page. Updates are "pushed" to customers (showing a badge on the App Store icon), and yes, I have no idea of the timing on this "push". I've only seen "Buy", "Download", and "Open" buttons on the App Store page, depending on the status of the app on each device.

Comment: I experienced this yesterday with an app that I updated. It took roughly 15 hours for the App Store page to update and for users to start getting the new version. Everything seems to be working fine now though.

Comment: I understand, but the users can see the new version on the App Store, but can't download it. So the new version is already available. When I'm on the "Update" tab, it doesn't appear, I have to looking for the app. But even in this case there is only the "Open" button.

Comment: It's been 28 hours of "ready to sale" for me, and still no update available for users.

Comment: @Cœur for me it was around 20 hours, are you sur you didn't turn on auto update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also released an app update yesterday. It took 20 hours for the update to appear for the first users. Seems like the App Store just has some hiccup currently...

Usually, an update button gets shown, so no worries.

Comment: Yes, but it already appears on the App Store. The thing is, I can't uploaded it, it's like I'm already updated. So I only have the "Open" button.

Comment: As pointed it, this is likely caused by some App Store hiccup and should be resolved sooner or later